UART1_Read_Text() function is not reading text data more than one bytes if I use ELSE condition
I was not able to read data more than one bytes.
void main(){
     char str[256] = "0";
     char st[256];
     TRISC6_bit = 0;   // Tx pin set as output
     TRISC7_bit = 1;   // Rx pin set as input

     UART1_Init(9600); // Initialize the UART with a baud rate of 9600

     Delay_ms(4);     //Wait for UART to stabilize

     while(1){
     
        if(UART1_Data_Ready() == 1){
            UART1_Read_Text(st, ";", 255);
            UART1_Write_Text(st);
             strcpy(str,st);
            UART1_Write_Text("\r\n");
            Delay_ms(1000);

        }
        else{
            UART1_Write_Text(str);
            UART1_Write_Text("\r\n");
            Delay_ms(1000);
        }
     }
 }

I want output of this below code like- initially it print the whatever have the initial value, it will keep on printing until I entered the new integer, again it will keep on printing(old value ) value until I entered the new value and so on. This below code works well for single digit Integer(0-9), when I read integer greater than 10, first time it get stuck, second time I read same value it print wrong value.
I have tried this example in the mikroC pro for pic compiler and pic18f67k40 microcontroller.
